# checkbox checked within a TBodies[0].rows iteration

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I simply need to check if the **checkbox** is checked within a `TBodies[0].rows` iteration. It's a legacy IE8 application.

```
var row = TABLE.tBodies[0].rows; // TABLE = id of the table
  for (var i = 0; i < row.length; i++) {
    if (row[i].cells[0].checked) { // this part does not work
      //... do something
    }
  }
```

Comment: use row.count instead of row.length

Comment: Can you show the html for the table please? Also, what do you wish to do if the checkbox is checked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only need to support browsers newer than IE8, you should be able to use the following:

```
var checkboxes = TABLE.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]');

for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
    if (checkboxes[i].checked) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

An example of the code is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4158opz5/).

Comment: Thx! It forgot to mention that its a IE8 application. I updated my question.

Comment: @oldsport IE8 should support `querySelectorAll()` as long as you only use CSS2 selectors.

Comment: @oldsport I just tested the code above with IE8 and it works as expected.